# How to start spyder

Tags: spyder

spyder will not work after installing Anaconda3-5.3.1-Windows-x86_64.exe on extra drive.
The error is: E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init*_.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered how to solve this problem myself. The PATH needs to be edited to add an additional path. The complete method is described in detail in:
[www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/](http://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

In my case I added E:\Anaconda3\Library\bin. Spyder now loads from the E drive.